# Is there a wildcard for setting up an Outlook 2007 rule?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I would like to create a rule that moves anything with the words `SUCCESS * BenchmarkResults`, where the `*` indicates a wildcard to a specific folder.  We have multiple systems that will be put in place of the `*`.

We have emails that will return `WARNING * BenchmarkResults` that I don't want the rule applied to.

I know I can create a separate rule for each of our systems, but I want this rule to be dynamic where I can add new benchmark emails without creating a new rule.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can write nested rules to accomplish what you are doing.  Have a rule on the Subject, and another rule on Subject or Body.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

From [using wild card characters in outlook rules](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3162356.php), Sue Mosher (author of Microsoft Outlook 2007 Programming:
Jumpstart for Power Users and Administrators) says, "Outlook does not support wild card characters in rules.".

Comment: I wish they had it. It would be a useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a *search list* when you edit the rule that you can add multiple search sentences. but again it seems that there is no wild cart search suppoerted in  my Office 365