# Copy message when subject is same in Outlook Emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In MS Outlook 2010, I want to copy all the messages (the actual content/body) if subject is "Order 2014".

So all emails whose subject heading is "Order 2014", their message content will be copied and be pasted on a single .txt file.

How to handle this? Please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a wildcard for setting up an outlook 2007 rule](http://superuser.com/questions/152825/is-there-a-wildcard-for-setting-up-an-outlook-2007-rule)

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort messages by subject
2. Select the messages with the subject "Order 2014"
   (Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with your left mouse button to select multiple messages)
3. File -> Save As